# Android Scrollview interpolation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview

is it possible to have interpolator on scrollview? I'd like to have nice animation when scrolling.

I have columns in horizontalscrollview, and I want to scroll to begining of each column with interpolator or sth simmilar.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using the HorizontalScrollView from the sdk, no.

The Scroller used in that view is declared private and no other access methods are provided.

You could extract the HorizontalScrollView code from the sdk and make changes that way.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking after it. But it's not so great to copy source and change access, how can I be sure that I have source that is Android 2.1. However is seams that there is some kind of interpolation already set in HSV. It's not great but until I have more time it will do the job. I implemented this little interpolation by extending onFling in onGestureLister, where I set smoothScrollTo one of the colums. But it's not so great because scroll animation is really fast... too fast when scrolling 2-3 columns.